# Unable to float nav-bar right with 100% width

Tags: html, css

When I float the below UI element to right. the width no longer remains 100% that is stretched across the page. Below is my HTML and CSS code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main-container">       
        <div id="image">
            <div id="nav-bar">
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Team</li>
                    <li>About us</li>
                    <li>Contact us</li>
                </ul>           
            </div>
            <img src="D75_9070.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#main-container {
background-color: black;
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

img {
    display: block;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#nav-bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

ul {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: white;

}

li {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question...

Comment: It is unclear what you actually ask... For example: _which_ UI element do you want to float right? The `<ul>`? What sense does floating to left or right make, if the width _remains_ at 100%? That is no floating then...

Comment: The question is there. I want the width to remain 100% while I float the navigation bar to right.

Comment: No, you did _not_ ask that. You only stated that it does not have that width any more. Which perfectly makes sense to me. You did not ask anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the background color to your `#nav-bar` instead, like this, while floating the `ul`.

```css
#main-container {
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#nav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

ul {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  float: right;
}

li {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">       
  <div id="image">
    <div id="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Team</li>
        <li>About us</li>
        <li>Contact us</li>
      </ul>           
    </div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/animals">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If a element has 100% width then floating it is meaningless (well mostly meaningless).

For something that is meant to stretch the entire width, floating it will make the parent container collapse, but it will not have any affect in terms of moving content to one side or another.

What I think you are looking for is this.

```
#nav-bar ul {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, this should have been a comment.

Comment: I would tend to agree but in this case there isn't really a question, and this explains why the requested functionality is not working as intended.

Comment: So you answered something where no question was asked? And then say it is correct to post that as an "answer"? And even _if_ that explains something, it still is _not_ an answer.

Comment: The OP wants something. A answer should provide something that fulfills what the OP wants. This does not :-) But don't get me wrong: what you say is true, I do not doubt that. It just does not answer the question _in my eyes_. Especially since we _still_ do not have a question... Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Simple add `text-align: right;` to `ul`

```
ul {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: right;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edtmLue0/)**